# Dynamically execute dependency blocks in terragrunt with for_each (or similar)

Tags: terraform, hcl, terragrunt

I'm trying to DRY/parametrize the dependency block of my terragrunt file for my multi-environments setup.

I've these dependencies:

```
dependency "development" {
  config_path = "../../development/mandatory_resources" }

dependency "production" {
  config_path = "../../production/mandatory_resources" }
```

that I use this way:

```
inputs = {
  projects                    = {
    "dev"  = dependency.development.outputs.shared_resources_project_id,
    "prod" = dependency.production.outputs.shared_resources_project_id, 
  }
}
```

Assuming I've the map of available environments in this third dependency `dependency.retrospect.outputs.available_environments` (coming from an earlier terragrunt stage)

```
{
"dev" = "development",
"prod" = "production",
}
```

I'm wondering if there is a more elegant way to have the same results without writing twice the dependency block and/or hardcoding the environments in the inputs block (this would also allow me to scale to N enviroments without breaking the  code). Is it possible with terragrunt? Perhaps using a for_each directive?